# Facebook Daily Like sources error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the api to pull data from the Facebook graph API. I have a few pages which does not have "like Ads" but when i Pull the data using this this data is comping out, but when using it extracting the data from the page insights this does not com up in the daily like sources any idea why this would be.

When I am looking at the data using the insights manager of the page the data is  "like Ads"  in the output, but when pulling this from the API  "like Ads" data seems to appear on the page data